# Using mock.patch's autospec option with a custom Mock subclass

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-mock

I'm trying to attach a spy to a method in a class using the (backported) [`mock`](https://github.com/testing-cabal/mock) module. That is, I want to create a mock which works like the original method but offers the usual `Mock` features like `call_count`, etc.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
import mock

class MyClass(object):
    def my_method(self, arg):
        return arg + 1

def unit_under_test():
    inst = MyClass()
    return inst.my_method(1)

with mock.patch.object(MyClass, 'my_method', autospec=True,
                       side_effect=MyClass.my_method) as spy:
    result = unit_under_test()
    assert result == 2
    assert spy.call_count == 1
```

That's working nicely. Now I want to use a custom subclass of `MagicMock` instead. The [`patch` documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) says that this can be done via the `new_callable` argument. However, `new_callable` and `autospec` cannot be used together:

```
class MyMock(mock.MagicMock):
    pass

with mock.patch.object(MyClass, 'my_method', autospec=True,
                       side_effect=MyClass.my_method,
                       new_callable=MyMock) as spy:
    ...
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mocktest.py", line 19, in <module>
    new_callable=MyMock) as spy:
  File "/var/foo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 1442, in _patch_object
    spec_set, autospec, new_callable, kwargs
  File "/var/foo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 1127, in __init__
    "Cannot use 'autospec' and 'new_callable' together"
ValueError: Cannot use 'autospec' and 'new_callable' together
```

The problem is that leaving out `autospec` doesn't work, either, because then `self` is not passed along to the original method:

```
with mock.patch.object(MyClass, 'my_method',
                       side_effect=MyClass.my_method,
                       new_callable=MyMock) as spy:
    ...
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mocktest.py", line 20, in <module>
    result = unit_under_test()
  File "./mocktest.py", line 11, in unit_under_test
    return inst.my_method(1)
  File "/var/foo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 955, in __call__
    return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/foo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 1018, in _mock_call
    ret_val = effect(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: unbound method my_method() must be called with MyClass instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

Note that I cannot patch `my_method` of a `MyClass` *instance* instead, since the code I'm testing creates its own `MyClass` instance (as shown in the example code above).

Comment: Dear downvoter, please provide a comment so that I can improve my question.

Comment: Is there more to the `MyMock` class than `pass`?

Comment: @kiminoa: In my original setup `MyMock` provides additional tools for working with the mock. However, as my example shows the problem still exists even for the trivial `pass`-only subclass.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `mock.py` [hardcodes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/01dceba13e872e9ca24b8e00a2b75db3d0d6c1a3/Lib/unittest/mock.py#L2750) `MagicMock` as the mock class when `autospec` is set.

A simple workaround then would be to patch `MagicMock` itself with your own:

```
with mock.patch.object(mock, 'MagicMock', MyMock):
    with mock.patch.object(MyClass, 'my_method', autospec=True,
                           side_effect=MyClass.my_method) as spy:
        ...
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/iPMnSc